# Git clone only a set of paths with full history

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm wondering if it is possible to clone only a set of specific paths from a repository, and the history of those files? Without having to clone the entire repository?

If not, is there a more-efficient way to go about this? I'd like to avoid cloning our entire repo regularly on our CI when I only need a small portion of the repo.

For example I have repository:

```
./
    - Src/
      - Dir1/
      - Dir2/
    - External/
      - Lib1/
        - file.cpp
      - Lib2/
        - file.cpp
      - Lib3/
    - Resources/
      - image.png
      - video.mp4
```

I want to clone only External/Lib1 and External/Lib2, as well as its history. I do not need to know about Resources, Source, Lib3, etc. So would be inefficient to clone these.

I have attempted to do this by doing

`git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --sparse <REPO>`

then

`git sparse-checkout set External/Lib1 External/Lib2`

Which works well, however I cannot see the history of the files using this method. If there is a way I can sparse-checkout the entire history of only those files, this method would be ideal.

Any help/advice appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1074185

Comment: @leun4m This is what I followed for the attempt in the question, but unfortunately doesn't provide the history of the files :( Thanks for the response though

Comment: Don't think you can. Git works on commits, so when you do a sparse checkout it can't map that to commits, and thus not to history.

Answer (score 0):

Our hosting service does not support partial clone. For CI jobs, we maintain a group of mirror repositories that CI jobs can access to. In practice, we use 2 strategies.

In the first strategy, the mirror repositories are created by `git clone --mirror`. They are bare repositories. When a CI job starts, it clones the repository with the option `--reference-if-able /path/to/mirror/repository`. This way, it borrows objects from the mirror repository and only fetches the missing objects that don't exist in the mirror repository. This option can be used with `--single-branch`, `--depth <n>` and `git sparse-checkout` if necessary. After the job, the CI repository is removed.

Regularly we update these bare repositories and run `git gc`, like once a day or once a week, so that the mirror repositories can hold as much data as possible.

In the second strategy, the mirror repositories are created by `git clone --no-checkout`. They are non-bare repositories without any checkout. When a CI job starts, it fetches the needed ref in the repository first and then it creates a work tree for the ref or commit by `git worktree add /path/to/worktree revision`. Sparse-checkout is also compatible with work trees. After the job, the CI work tree is removed. According to our experience, it's better to create the work trees on the same disk where the mirror repositories are located.

For these non-bare repositories, we run `git gc` regularly. When there are too many loose objects, some git commands would become very slow.

With the help of mirror repositories, we find a point where storage cost, time cost and network cost are all balanced.